# using document.querySelector with complex CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

In JavaScript I want to use `document.querySelector` to "grab" the last div (`<div class="widget-footer">`) in below HTML. However after many tries, I still can't figure out the correct CSS selector syntax to use.

The following code does not work:

```
document.querySelector (".skin-grid-widgets.ui-sortable.gridWidgetTemplatePositie.AgendaStandaard.disablesorting.hoogte-1-knoppen-0.breedte-1.widget-footer")
```

Here is the HTML I am working with

```
<div class="skin-grid enkeleKolom" id="Infobalk">
    <div class="skin-grid-widgets ui-sortable">
        <div class="gridWidgetTemplatePositie AgendaStandaard disablesorting hoogte-1-knoppen-0 breedte-1">
            <div class="widget-header">
                here comes the header text
             </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                some body text
            </div>   
            <div class="widget-footer">
                here comes the footer text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've surfed everywhere to find example of complex CSS selectors used with querySelector, but to no avail. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: because you do not have an element with the `class="skin-grid-widgets ui-sortable gridWidgetTemplatePositie AgendaStandaard disablesorting hoogte-1-knoppen-0 breedte-1 widget-footer"`

Comment: use jquery, and all of your problems will be solved. mostly.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb That is funny.... How would it be solved when querySelector selects elements in the same manner.

Comment: I have a feeling the route cause of the issue is trying to reference element before it is rendered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @epascarello I agree, considering my demo is working with the provided HTML

Comment: @epascarello, it's a joke. mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you need a space in between each child element you are trying to select. If you do not have spaces in between your class selectors, by CSS specification, it will look for **both** classes on the **same** element.

Change your selector to look like the following:

```js
var footer = document.querySelector(".skin-grid-widgets.ui-sortable .gridWidgetTemplatePositie.AgendaStandaard.disablesorting.hoogte-1-knoppen-0.breedte-1 .widget-footer");

footer.classList.add("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="skin-grid enkeleKolom" id="Infobalk">
    <div class="skin-grid-widgets ui-sortable">
        <div class="gridWidgetTemplatePositie AgendaStandaard disablesorting hoogte-1-knoppen-0 breedte-1">
            <div class="widget-header">
                here comes the header text
             </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                some body text
            </div>   
            <div class="widget-footer">
                here comes the footer text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was one of the things I already tried. This code still returns "bummer": (document.querySelector(".skin-grid-widgets.ui-sortable .gridWidgetTemplatePositie.AgendaStandaard.disablesorting.hoogte-1-knoppen-0.breedte-1 .widget-footer") !== null){
    alert("STRIKE");
} else {
    alert("BUMMER");
}

Comment: @DirkBomans Then either you still have a typo, your DOM does not look like you have shown, or you have a timing issue

Comment: @DirkBomans Are these elements being added dynamically? Also, are you loading your script in the `<head>` tag, or at the bottom of your `<body>`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
   document.querySelector (".skin-grid-widgets .gridWidgetTemplatePositie .widget-footer");
</script>
```

You don't need to add adjacent classes like "skin-grid-widgets ui-sortable" in querySelector, if you do so then query selector assumes that   "skin-grid-widgets" is parent of  "ui-sortable". Use just one of the classes at one DOM level.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

The selector ain't complex, your thoughts are.

Listen to yourself, to the description you provide of what you want to select:

> "grab" the last div in below HTML

Not grab the node with the class `widget-footer` inside of a node that has all these classes: `gridWidgetTemplatePositie AgendaStandaard disablesorting hoogte-1-knoppen-0 breedte-1`, inside a node ...

```
//a utility, because DRY.
//and because it's nicer to work with Arrays than with NodeLists or HTMLCollections.
function $$(selector, ctx=document){
    return Array.from(ctx.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

//and the last div in this document:
var target = $$('div').pop();
```

or

> "grab" `<div class="widget-footer">` in below HTML

```
var target = document.querySelector("div.widget-footer");
```

or the combination: grab the last `div.widget-footer` in the HTML

```
var target = $$('div.widget-footer').pop();
```

Comment: It depends on how many assumptions you can make. For example, I find it unlikely that you can just do document.querySelector("div.widget-footer") because that assumes that there is only one div.widget-footer in the entire document (unless you think that fragment is all there is in the entire page...). There's probably a very good reason the asker wants the div.widget-footer only in that particular ancestor - and therefore a very good reason why their thoughts are that complex.

Comment: What I find most amusing about this is that you specify a ctx argument in your $$ definition... but your example just goes with the default of the document object anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock, that's the ambiguity between what the asker is describing what he wants and what he's trying. Finally he's the only one who knows what his entire document structure looks like. I was orientating on what he describes he wants and not on his failing attempt to implement it.

Comment: @BoltClock And about `$$` and the amusing `ctx`. This utility is oversized for this specific task, but in my experience this won't stay the only place in a page one wants to select a list of nodes and somehow iterate/process them. And although most of the time I use `document` as the context for the queries, sometimes I need a different Element there. And I don't want, that I have to be explicit/repeat myself, for like 90% of the default cases, like I don't want to write another (pretty much identical) function for these 10% of cases.